# applying a path curve as a taper object causes my bevel round with defined depth to disappear

Tags: edit-mode

I am struggling to apply a taper object to the stem of the mushroom as shown in this video in  parallel to the bevel with round of a defined depth. I have tried the different taper radius options but it does not seem to have any effect.

[image]

https://youtu.be/LdpQx1lwfLQ?t=167

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file

Comment: @moonboots: not sure how to share the file on this platform...

Comment: Here's how to share: [How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)

Comment: thats a nice feature. File is added. thanks!

Comment: fwiw, I have looked at your file and I can't find the problem.  It's possible that you've managed to encounter a bug.  Have you thought about trying a Bezier curve for the taper instead of the NurbsPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is to do with the units set-up in my model. By default a cylinder (mushroom stem) is added with dimension of radius/depth of 1000m/2000m respectively.

For my 3d print - the stem is only 20mm high. So by entering a large value (5000mm) for the Bevel -> round -> depth, the stem "re-appears".

[image]